# Getting breadcrumbs in laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, breadcrumbs

I'm using the davejamesmiller package to get the breadcrumbs and I don't think I'm understanding it very well.

I keep getting an error on my dynamically created pages that says

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/app/views/layouts/home.blade.php) (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/app/views/layouts/home.blade.php)

When I use this code

```
Breadcrumbs::register('page', function($breadcrumbs, $page) {
    $breadcrumbs->parent('home');
    $breadcrumbs->push($page->title, route('page', $page->id));
});
```

Here is all my code

home.blade.php

```
            <!-- HEADER -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                <div class="heading">
                    <h2>Testing</h2>
                </div>
                {{ Breadcrumbs::render() }}

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- HEADER -->
```

and this is my app/breadcrumbs.php

```
Breadcrumbs::register('home', function($breadcrumbs) {
    $breadcrumbs->push('Home', route('home'));
});

Breadcrumbs::register('page', function($breadcrumbs, $page) {
    $breadcrumbs->parent('home');
    $breadcrumbs->push($page->title, route('page', $page->id));
});
```

My routes

```
Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'HomeController@index', 'as' => 'home']);

Route::get('page/{id}', ['uses' => 'ContentController@show', 'as' => 'page']);
```

If there is anything else that I need to give please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because you have pass nothing to your breadcrumbs.

```
{{ Breadcrumbs::render() }}
```

You should do something like this:

```
{{ Breadcrumbs::render('home', $page) }}
```

Code:

```
 <!-- HEADER -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
            <div class="heading">
                <h2>Testing</h2>
            </div>
            {{ Breadcrumbs::render('home', $page) }}

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- HEADER -->
```